# Spring boot custom query in repository with the error of NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am playing with spring boot to build web APIs using @query to get a question(DB table) item from the Question table based on question's description and type. 
Code in the Repository:

```
@Query(
        value = "select * from question q where q.description like %:desc% and q.question_type = :type",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    public Optional<Question> findByDescAndTitle(@Param("desc") String desc,
                                                 @Param("type") String type);
```

Code I Run the method findByDescAndTitle:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.enmasseQuiz.runners;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.enmasseQuiz.models.Question;
import com.enmasseQuiz.repos.QuestionRepo;

/**
 * @author leoliu
 *
 */
@Component
public class QuizCommandRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepo questionRepo;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("=== Available services: ");
        for (Question q: this.questionRepo.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(q);
        }

        System.out.println(this.questionRepo.findByDescAndTitle("MVP", "mcq"));
    }

}
```

But when I try to run, it always give me the NullPointerException error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:781) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at com.enmasseQuiz.EnmasseQuizApplication.main(EnmasseQuizApplication.java:16) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1186) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:376) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:278) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1054) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5177) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getInstanceClass(Loader.java:1808) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1633) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1562) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:991) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2200) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1463) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:380) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.getSingleResult(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:214) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.findByDescAndTitle(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.enmasseQuiz.runners.QuizCommandRunner.run(QuizCommandRunner.java:30) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
```

I am using Java 8 and Spring boot 2 with Gradle. Being searching for couple of days but not one seems to mention this error:

> CaseInsensitiveComparator

EnmasseQuizApplication.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EnmasseQuizApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EnmasseQuizApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The database table is simple like following:
[database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aeUT.png)

I am pretty new to Spring boot framework, and don't know how to debug this issue. It is really appreciated if someone can help out.

Comment: @JBNizet Hi, I am a newbie trying to follow the tutorial which lets me use native SQL. Do you think that is the main cause to the problem? Why JPQL is better? better performance? For find "ByTitle", I just use it for playing around, see if I could use custom query to fetch the record I expect.Currently there will be only one record for testing purpose.

Comment: Post the code where you call `findByDescAndTitle`

Comment: JPQL is better because it's simpler, uses your object model (which is the whole point of JPA) rather than the underlying SQL model, and allows querying for objects directly. It's also better because Spring-data will be able to verify that your JPQL query is valid, at startup time.

Comment: @JohnJoe just added where I call findByDescAndTitle, thanks

Comment: @JBNizet thanks JB that makes sense. I will change to JPQL rather than native sql

Comment: also post the code in `EnmasseQuizApplication.java:16`

Comment: @JohnJoe Just updated the question to include EnmasseQuizApplication code, thanks

Comment: Did this line compiled ? `System.out.println("=== Available services: ");`

Comment: @JohnJoe Nope, yet, actually this was fixed already. I actually used JPQL rather than native sql. Direct mapping might help